# How to output total number of professions in SQL based on 4 tables

Tags: sql, error-handling

I have the following tables available through this link:
[tables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NjrOa.png).
I'm trying to do a query where I list out the degrees (profession) and the counts associated with that profession. If the degree is listed more than twice, it should output 'Popular Degree'. I coded:

```
select profession, count(profession_id), count(profession_id) > 2 as Popular
from Profession
where profession_id in
(select profession_id from provider_profession)
group by profession
```

I get an output of this, which is wrong:
[My query result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uIT4q.png)

I am not sure how to query the result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```sql
select p.profession, 
count(pp.provider_id), 
case 
   when count(pp.provider_id)>2 then 'Popular degree'
   else ''
end as DegreePopularity
from profession p inner join provider_profession pp on p.profession_id=pp.profession_id
group by p.profession
```

I have tried to keep the answer as close to ANSI sql as possible, though only tested it out on a sql server

Comment: Thank you!! I see what I did wrong now. It is definitely easier to use a join on the tables.

Answer (score 1):

replace `count(profession_id) > 2 as Popular` with `(case when count(profession_id) > 2 then 1 else 0 end) as Popular`

Comment: I used that pointer and replaced it with the case but it is not properly counting the total count per degree

Comment: Can you please post more query output. Your image doesn't show any lines where the count is greater than 2.

Comment: That's why I'm confused. It is not counting greater than 1, but obviously the table has more than 1 count per degree. Whatever is in the pic I linked is my output

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/bccd8f/4 this is a diffrent table but you got the idea

Comment: Your fiddle shows John's code working as required, no?